# make4ht fails on valid tex file but pdflatex works

Tags: make4ht

I am trying to convert a tex file into HTML using make4ht. pdflatex successfully outputs a PDF, but make4ht fails. I have a test file as below

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

When I comment any ONE of `tikz` or `tkz-graph`, make4ht works but fails when both are present.

Here is the log-

```
[INFO]    mkparams: Output dir: 
[INFO]    mkparams: Compiler: latex
[INFO]    mkparams: Latex options: -jobname=test  
[INFO]    mkparams: tex4ht.sty: xhtml,
[INFO]    mkparams: tex4ht: 
[INFO]    mkparams: build_file: test.mk4
[INFO]    mkparams: Output format: html5
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: test.tex
[INFO]    mkutils: Load extension   common_domfilters
[INFO]    mkutils: Cannot open config file  test.mk4
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: setting param correct_exit
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: setting param correct_exit
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: setting param correct_exit
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: setting param ext
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: Adding:  ext dvi
[INFO]    htlatex: LaTeX call: latex --interaction=errorstopmode -jobname=test   '\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar ....(so on)
...
...
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-graph/tkz-graph.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/usepackage.4ht)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\use:tikzlibrary #1->\use:tikzlibrary {#1
                                         }\find:externalize #1external\@nil 
l.23 \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
                            
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1
```

(Full log [here](https://gist.github.com/AvyChanna/3295ce8c26b4b609af543cf51a066110) if needed)

Latex distribution from [https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive) on Ubuntu Bionic 18.04.5

```
$ latex -v
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
Copyright 2019 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.34
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.01
```

Comment: I think you TeX distribution is a bit old. I don't get any compilation error with up-to date TeX Live 2020.

Comment: @michal.h21 I'm using this distribution to reproduce the build environment on Travis CI. Maybe I should look into changing it too. Thank You

Comment: there was lot of changes in both LaTeX core and TeX4ht in the past year, so I highly suggest to try more recent distro :)